# How to use mutable member Vec?

Tags: rust, lifetime

How to properly create a member `Vec`? What am I missing here?

```
struct PG {
    names: &mut Vec<String>,
}

impl PG {
    fn new() -> PG {
        PG { names: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn push(&self, s: String) {
        self.names.push(s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pg = PG::new();
    pg.push("John".to_string());
}
```

If I compile this code, I get:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:2:12
  |
2 |     names: &mut Vec<String>,
  |            ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

If I change the type of `names` to `&'static mut Vec<String>`, I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
7 |         PG { names: Vec::new() }
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^
  |                     |
  |                     expected mutable reference, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
  |                     help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut Vec::new()`
  |
  = note: expected type `&'static mut std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
             found type `std::vec::Vec<_>`
```

I know I can use parameterized lifetimes, but for some other reason I have to use `static`.

Comment: Maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413364/as-i-can-make-the-vector-is-mutable-inside-struct#36720608

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need any lifetimes or references here:

```
struct PG {
    names: Vec<String>,
}

impl PG {
    fn new() -> PG {
        PG { names: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, s: String) {
        self.names.push(s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pg = PG::new();
    pg.push("John".to_string());
}
```

Your `PG` struct *owns* the vector - not a reference to it. This does require that you have a mutable `self` for the `push` method (because you are changing `PG`!). You also have to make the `pg` variable mutable.

Comment: Great! I'm still confused, though. `pg` and `self` need to be mutable, but `names` doesn't? I thought I was changing `names`, not `pg`. I will study more, if I can find good material about that. Thank you!

Comment: @paulolieuthier Structs are entirely mutable or not. By having `pg` mutable, you are *able* to call the method that requires a mutable self reference. **Every** field of `PG` is mutable within that method, including `names`.