# As I can make the vector is mutable inside struct

Tags: rust

As I can make the vector is mutable

```
pub struct Test<'a>{
    vec: &'a mut Vec<i32>,
}
impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    pub fn created()->Test<'a>{
        Test {vec: &'a mut Vec::new() }
    }
    pub fn add(&self, value: i32){  
        self.vec.push(value);
    }
}
```

---

```
expected `:`, found `mut`
Test {vec: &'a mut Vec::new() }
               ^~~
```

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415521/how-to-use-mutable-member-vec) but

and the answer works, but what if I do not want, you can do this, "applying the response link"

```
pub struct Test{
    vec: Vec<i32>,
}
impl Test {
    pub fn created()->Test {
        Test {vec: Vec::new() }
    }
    pub fn add(&mut self, value: i32){  
        self.vec.push(value);
    }
}
..//
let mut test: my::Test = my::Test::created();
test.add(1i32);

let mut test1: my::Test = my::Test::created();

test1 = test; <-- I do not want, you can do this
..//
```

as I can make the vector is mutable, without making it be all the struct

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html). Please, do not use interior mutability loosely, read [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) first.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub struct Test{
    vec: RefCell<Vec<i32>>,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn created()->Test {
        Test {vec: RefCell::new(Vec::new()) }
    }
    pub fn add(&self, value: i32){  
        self.vec.borrow_mut().push(value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = Test::created();
    test.add(1i32);

    let test1 = Test::created();
    // test1 = test; // does not work anymore
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, and the recommendation of the link for this case

Comment: The book link is pretty old and it links to a section of the new book that doesn't discuss "interior mutability"; I think you'll want https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html